# python recursion jumping to last cell

Tags: python, recursion

im trying to figure out how to write a recursive python program which takes a list

i.e [1,2,3,4,0] while each number donates the number of steps you can take left or right. and figure out of a way you to get to the zero cell at the end.

for example [3,6,4,1,3,4,2,5,3,0] , if i start at the leftmost cell(3), i could take:
    3 steps right to the 1 cell ->
    1 step back to the 4 cell ->
    4 steps right to the 2 cell- >
    2 steps right to the 3 cell ->
    3 steps left to the 4 cell ->
    and 4 steps right to the 0 cell

i can start on any cell on the board.. and also need to figure out when it is not possible to solve the board.

how do i start to think about this using recursion?

```
def is_solvable(start, board):

if board[start] == 0:
     return True
if (start + board[start] == board[start+1] and start+board[start] > len(board)-1):
    return False
else:
    if start + board[start] <= len(board)-1:
        print(board[start])
        return(is_solvable(start+board[start] , board))
    if start - board[start] >= 0:
        print(board[start])
        return(is_solvable(start-board[start] , board))

board = [1,1,2,0]
start = 0
print(is_solvable(start, board))
```

my problem is i get stuck in [1,1,2,0] for example in an infinite loop sending me back to 1 all the time.. i need help writing trhe conditions to avoids these cases...basically i want ro return False if the pazzle is not solvable and True if it is. (my "if" condition on top is all wrong)

Comment: The key is to keep a list of places you have already been, so you can detect a cycle.

Comment: yeah im thinking in that direction but pretty clueless on how to approach it. would love some help on how to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
def is_solvable(index, board, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = []

    if index == len(board) - 1:
        return True
    elif index in visited:
        return False
    elif index < 0 or index >= len(board):
        # out of bounds
        return False
    else:
        visited.append(index)
        value = board[index]
        left = is_solvable(index - value, board, visited)
        right = is_solvable(index + value, board, visited)
        return left or right
```

Note that instead of manually checking to make sure we don't overflow the board, we let it happen, and add out-of-bounds checking to our list of base cases.

If you're not allowed to change the arguments the function receives, (or are not allowed to make a second function), I suppose you could mutate the board instead:

```
def is_solvable(index, board):
    if index == len(board) - 1:
        return True
    elif board[index] is None:
        return False
    elif index < 0 or index >= len(board):
        # out of bounds
        return False
    else:
        value = board[index]
        board[index] = None

        left = is_solvable(index - value, board, visited)
        right = is_solvable(index + value, board, visited)
        return left or right
```

Comment: this works.. gonna study the concept and write my own code, thanks! also thanks pop and everyone who helped me.

Comment: can you explain what the "return left or right" mean at the end? having trouble following the logic of that line. how does it know what to return?

Comment: @user2970357 -- The variable `left` is true if jumping to the left by `value` spaces eventually lets you finish. Similarly, the variable `right` is true if jumping right by `value` spaces lets you finish. The function should return `False` if neither `left` nor `right` are true, and should return `True` if one or both of the variables are true. If we draw out a boolean truth table, this is equivalent to the `or` boolean comparison. Hence, doing `return left or right` returns False only if both paths are invalid, and `true` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will really help you, but I'll just give the answer... The key with recursive function is thinking:

1. What's my base case (when do I terminate)
2. What recursive call can I make that makes the problem smaller
3. Convince yourself that it will always terminate.

   ```
   def is_solvable(pos,board):
       return is_solvable(pos,board,[])

   def is_solvable(pos,board,seen):
       if pos < 0 or pos >= len(board) or pos in seen:
           return False
       if board[pos] == 0:
           return True
       seen.append(pos)
       return is_solvable(pos + board[pos],board,seen) or is_solvable(pos + board[pos],board,seen)

   board = [1,1,2,0]
   seen = list()
   start = 0
   print(is_solvable(start, board,seen))
   ```

Comment: pop im not allowed to change the vars the function gets.. damn rules:). also not allowed to write anything outside the function. the stuffi wrote is just for internal testing.

Comment: You can create a helper function with different arguments that `is_solvable` calls.